# How to correctly change directory/file rights (with chmod 777)?

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, azure-cli

I cd to:

```
'/Users/name/.azure/config'
```

Where I execute:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./
```

Then when I try to run:

```
az configure --defaults group=fake-resource-group
```

I get:

```
Permission denied: '/Users/name/.azure/config'
```

It only works if I do:

```
sudo az configure --defaults group=learn-bda08cf1-281d-4b2e-ae5a-adc1dde7bd11
```

So it looks like the chmod was not successful or something?

Why is this and how to resolve?

Comment: You might also need to `sudo chown` for the duration of this run.

Comment: It could be a lot of things, but you're giving little detail.  For instance, the output of `ls -ld /Users/name/.azure/config` would be useful.  Also, you're not using the same command when running `sudo` (`group` argument has changed) so it's unclear if the problem is related to that, at least for people not familiar with `az`.  Also, is there other output when you run the command without `sudo` and get “Permission denied”?